# Find out string that would come in first in dictionary among strings generated by combination of given strings

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures, permutation

Given a list of strings of different length, we need find out string that would come in first in dictionary among strings generated by combination of given strings.

For Input:
cda,bcs,fgr,cd

output should be bcscdcdefgr

Is there any better way than generating all the combinations of strings and comparing them? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you just want ascending dictionary order.  If so, then a plain collections sort should work here:

```java
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "cda", "bcs", "fgr", "cd" });
Collections.sort(words);
String output = String.join("", words);
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
bcscdcdafgr
```

Comment: This would fail for the input `{"b","ba","c"}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach. Sorting directly would fail as `b` would before `ba`.

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"b","ba","c"});
            
Collections.sort(words,new Comparator<String>(){
   @Override
   public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
      return (s1+s2).compareTo(s2+s1);
   }
});
            
String output = String.join("", words);
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: The OP appears to want `b` to come before `ba`.  Please re-read the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen For `{"b","ba","c"}` , simple sorting and joining would produce `bbac`. But `babc` would come first in a dcitionary right?

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple observation, as to why a simple sort wouldn't work. Sorting `["b", "bb", "bba"]` in descending order will give you `["bba", "bb", "b"]`. However, the word that would occur first in a dictionary would've been `["bb", "bba", "b"]`.
You need to create a comparator, where you can compare strings `x` and `y` as follows:

1. Create `string a = x+y` and `string b = y+x` (basically `xy` and `yx`)
2. Compare `a` and `b`. If `a>b`, that means `x` should be put first to achieve the correct dictionary order. Otherwise `y` should be put first.

A simple of doing that would be:

```
static void printLargest(Vector<String> arr)
{
    Collections.sort(arr, new Comparator<String>()
    {
        @Override public int compare(String X, String Y)
        {
            String XY = X + Y;
            String YX = Y + X;
            return XY.compareTo(YX) > 0 ? -1 : 1;
        }
    });
}
```

This solution uses no extra space and has `O(NlogN)` time complexity.